# Reloading a larger div after a smaller divs are triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created three `onclick` trigger functions that trigger three separate divs in a larger div "main". For some reason, the function only works after one click, then I have to refresh the page.

For example, if I click to trigger the sports function, I have to refresh the page before I can use the news button. From there I have to refresh the page. How do I get the main div to reload before I trigger a second or third event? I've tried `location.reload()`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```html
<div id="main">

 <div id="news">
<h2 id="newsbtn"> News </h2>
</div>  

<div id="interactive">
<h2 id="interactivebtn"> Interactive</h2>
</div>

<div id="sports">
<h2 id="sportsbtn"> Sports </h2>
</div>

</div>
```

```javascript
$( "#newsbtn" ).click(function() {
$("#sports").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
  $("#interactive").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})


$( "sportsbtn" ).click(function() {
$("#interactive").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
  $("#news").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})


$( "#interactivebtn" ).click(function() {
  $("#sports").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
$("#news").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})


$( "#news" ).click(function() {
$("#sports").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
  $("#interactive").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})
;})
```

Comment: try and post code that is recreatable to your situation.

Comment: can you show the html of your page?

Comment: <div id="main">
<div id="news"></div>
<div id="interactive"></div>
<div id="sports"></div>
</div>

Comment: How do you plan to click one of the other elements after you have hidden them? Generally, each element would have a container with a header and a content area and only the content area would be hidden leaving the header to be clicked

Comment: You're hiding your stuff without ever showing them again.

Comment: Everything shows up at the beginning. It just doesn't refresh after the first event. Say I click the newsbtn, when I click sportsbtn the page goes blank so I have to refresh.

Comment: the page doesn't got blank, you're hiding all the elements and giving no mechanism to re-show them

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are basically trying to make an accordian.

That being the case, you're currently hiding all the other elements when one element is clicked. After that, you cant click one of the other elements because you have hidden them.

Generally, for an accordian, each element would have a container with a header and a content area and only the content area would be hidden leaving the header to be clicked

Here is a simple (and not perfect) example, if this is indeed what you are wanting:

```js
$("#main").on('click', '.selectable-container .header', function() { 
  var $container=$(this).closest('.selectable-container');
  $('.selectable-container').not($container).find('.content').fadeOut("slow", "linear");
  $container.find('.content').fadeIn("slow", "linear");
})
```

```css
.selectable-container .content{
  display:none;
}
.selectable-container .header{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="news selectable-container"> 
    <div class="header">news</div>
    <div class="content">news content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="interactive selectable-container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">header content</div>
    </div>
  <div class="sports selectable-container">
    <div class="header">sports</div>
    <div class="content">sports content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```